# cabal update causes segmentation fault on FreeBSD 10.2

Tags: freebsd, haskell, cabal

I have installed `FreeBSD 10.2-RELEASE` 32-bit and I am trying to use Haskell on it.

I have installed package `ghc-7.10.2` with `pkg` and then installed package `hs-cabal-install-1.22.6.0` from `/usr/ports/devel/hs-cabal-install`.

Now, when I run `cabal update` I get:

```
$ cabal update
Downloading the latest package list from hackage.haskell.org
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Running it as root causes the same problem.

I have been searching on different search engines but found no article describing this specific problem. Can you give me some hint on how to solve this problem or where I can find some documentation about it?

Comment: There is a bug report at https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=204290, which states that is has something to do with LLVm support. Did you change any of the `make config` values? You might consider to add the configuration options to your question.

Comment: @RaphaelAhrens: Thanks for the hint. The problem was probably related to this bug. I had indeed chosen LLVM support. I have rebuilt everything and now it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [bug report](https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=204290) which describes the same issue. There seems to be a problem when the port is compiled with LLVM support, which causes segmentation faults.

You need to run

```
cd /usr/ports/devel/hs-cabal-install
make config
```

to unset the LLVM support and to so avert the problem.